# PNG only shows up on chrome but not safari or firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

It's pretty weird the background image and the logo won't show on Firefox or Safari

Below is my code I cut the HTMl and the CSS down to the only ones that are not showing which is "logo" and the background.

CSS

```
      body {
      background: url("/images/bg1.png") no-repeat fixed;
}

      #logo {
        position: absolute;
        top: 17%;
        left: 15%;
        height: 17%;
        width: auto;
      }
```

HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<img class="animated shake" id="arrow" src="images/next.png">

<div class="topnav" id="mytopbar">
  <a><button id="donate">Donate</button></a>
  <a>Contact Us</a>
  <a>Whats New</a>
  <a>Shop</a>
</div>

<img id="logo" class="animated bounceInDown" src="/images/Logo.png">
```

Comment: Could it be the missing `}` here `body {
  background: url("/images/bg1.png") no-repeat fixed;` <<<<

Comment: It could be what @mplungjan and it also could be background: instead of background-image:

Comment: the missing bracket was a typo I delete by accident its in the original code

Comment: @WesleyCenatus can you update your code by giving us the picture files? Upload them to imgur.com and place it in the code please.

Answer (score 0):

Please find updated code below:

```
body {
  background: url( "http://www.vlime.co.nz/images/buttons/backgroundimage.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17%;
  left: 15%;
  height: 17%;
  width: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Cozmoz/9mkoqp77/